# Error "no version information available" Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I want to execute a "Qt Quick Controls Application" from windows to Raspberry pi3.
I use this link:
https://visualgdb.com/tutorials/raspberry/qt/embedded/

I can run "Qt Widgets Application" on Raspberry from windows but I can not run "Qt Quick Controls Application" and I have this error:

```
/home/pi/untitled4: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Qml.so.5: no version information available (required by /home/pi/untitled4)
/home/pi/untitled4: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Gui.so.5: no version information available (required by /home/pi/untitled4)
/home/pi/untitled4: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libQt5Core.so.5: no version information available (required by /home/pi/untitled4)
QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
qrc:/main.qml:2 module "QtQuick" is not installed
```

**Update:**
I reinstalled Qt and I have new error:

```
QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.
Unable to query physical screen size, defaulting to 100 dpi.
To override, set QT_QPA_EGLFS_PHYSICAL_WIDTH and QT_QPA_EGLFS_PHYSICAL_HEIGHT (in millimeters).
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
qrc:/main.qml:2 module "QtQuick.Controls" plugin "qtquickcontrolsplugin" not found
```

Comment: Reinstalling/Installing a newer version of Qt may solve your problem.